# Can a mathematics journal reject a paper because of using an unpublished paper?

Tags: mathematics, journals, paper-submission

I am a postdoc in math. Recently, I wrote a paper in which I used a theorem from a friend's paper. She left academia 6 months ago. Her paper has not been submitted to a journal but it is on [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/). I read her paper and believe that it is correct.

Can a journal reject my paper because her paper isn't published?

Comment: If one journal does then you submit to another journal which isn't so stupid.

Comment: If the journal objects, there are several ways to proceed. If your friend's paper is reasonably short, you can ask if it can be added to your paper as an appendix. Another option: if the proof of the specific result from that paper is short you can ask if it can be added as an appendix...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you give proper citation then it is unlikely that a journal would reject your paper without review. The reviewers might question the validity of the other paper, of course, which would bring the validity of yours into question.

Note that putting a paper on arXiv *is* publishing, though without the usual review.

---

Note how much scholarship would be slowed if no journal would look at any paper until all cited papers had actually appeared in formal (reviewed) venues. That process can take up to a year - or even longer. There would be no such thing as a "hot" topic.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know they review the paper. I meant that they say something like " Since you used a paper that is not published, we reject your paper".

Comment: Very unlikely unless, as Alexander Woo suggests, the editor is very stupid. Even completely unpublished "private communications" can be used, though they may draw extra scrutiny from reviewers.

Comment: Oh! thanks! your comment make me feel better; thanks!

Comment: @Adam You say "something like ..." in your comment. If you [edit] the question to show us the precise wording, and tell us that's the _only_ reason given for rejection, we might be able to say more.

Comment: @EthanBolker, I don't read the question as implying that it has happened, but only wondering if it is likely.

Comment: _Nature_ in particular explicitly mentions in its guidelines for authors that citations can be to published papers or to preprints on public preprint servers.

Answer (score 2):

There are tons of published papers that cite arXiv papers, so the answer is "no".

Here is one [paper](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=Counting%20Vacua%20in%20Random%20Landscapes&btnG=) I'm aware of that has been on the arXiv for years but has never been submitted to a journal. According to Google Scholar, it has been cited 23 times as of time of writing.

Answer (score 1):

I have to (weakly) disagree with Buffy.

If you're a reviewer, you may assume that a published peer-reviewed result is correct. If you rely on a result that has not gone through peer-review, then you essentially ask the reviewer to find the arxiv paper and (for all intents and purposes) review that paper first. That might not be what they signed up for.

A reviewer may therefore ask you to provide a proof of the result you rely, and thus reject the paper until that's in place.

Comment: How is it different if the OP provides a proof as opposed to the original providing it? Review is still needed in such a case. And, replicating the proof in another paper is a copyright violation. The job of the reviewer is only marginally harder.

Comment: I think this answer needs some qualification, in particlar the sentence *"If you're a reviewer, you may assume that a published peer-reviewed result is correct."* How much credibility one gives to a result in a paper depends on various factors, peer review is only one of which. I could (but for obvious reasons won't) name mathematicians, call them A and B, such that I will easily believe most results that A uploads on arXiv, while I wouldn't believe a word in an article of B without checking the details myself, no matter whether peer reviewed or not.

Comment: @Buffy I'm not saying to copy-paste the proof without crediting the source, most papers are in any case cc-by (on arxiv).

Comment: @JochenGlueck yes, that's why I say that a reviewer _might_ ask you to provide a proof. Anyone can put stuff on arxiv, if you use a bunch of unpublished results by random people, I don't think the reviewer is going to be happy.

Comment: @Buffy the difference is that you're reviewing OP's paper, not the paper on arxiv. You can't give feedback and ask for improvements on someone else's arxiv paper.

Comment: @PålGD "most papers are in any case cc-by (on arxiv)" Do you have a reference for this claim? It would be an interesting recent development, because [the data from 2015-2018 showed that the dominant license was the default arXiv one](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/115743/17254).

Comment: Oh wow, I stand corrected!